# What are the last 16 bytes in the crypto text output from the Microsoft AES implementation

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am currently implementing code using AES CBC in Microsoft NET System.Security.Cryptography and noticed something weird: there are 16 bytes at the end of each ciphertext which don’t seem to belong there.

Trying to find more information about what those 16 bytes might represent, or what data they might hold, I’ve searched all over the internet for related information – without any success.

Trying to figure it out nevertheless, I even ran some experiments setting the key, the IV and the plain text to 16 0x00s. By comparing the ciphertexts with another platform's AES CBC implementation, I verified that the first bytes are valid AES CBC ciphertext. The only difference is that NET seems to add 16 bytes at the end of the ciphertext.

Now, I don't believe it is padding because:

```
the cypher text for an additional block of sixteen 0's is different
as are manually entering the padding for PKCS7, ANSI X.923, and ISO7816-4.
```

Further research leads me to conclude the M$ padding modes in .NET appear to ignore the "PaddingMode" setting.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Plain Text

66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2EF795BD4A52E29ED713D313FA20E98DBC5C047616756FDC1C32E0DF6E8C59BB2A None
66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2EF795BD4A52E29ED713D313FA20E98DBC5C047616756FDC1C32E0DF6E8C59BB2A Zeros
66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2EF795BD4A52E29ED713D313FA20E98DBC5C047616756FDC1C32E0DF6E8C59BB2A PKCS7
66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2EF795BD4A52E29ED713D313FA20E98DBC5C047616756FDC1C32E0DF6E8C59BB2A ANSIX923
66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2EF795BD4A52E29ED713D313FA20E98DBC5C047616756FDC1C32E0DF6E8C59BB2A ISO7816
```

Besides that, I’m optimistically assuming those bytes aren’t merely something only Microsoft knows about. Is there some paper, reference, or documentation I failed to find, which might explain those last 16 bytes? What am I missing?

Comment: You need to post your code for a useful answer. It's also possible that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If you don't want .net to pad your data set the Padding of Rijndael to `PaddingMode.None`.

Comment: In VS 2015 I don't believe the padding option works:  My output was identical for all 5 options.

Comment: I verified the crypto-text against another platform's output and it matches up to the last 16 bytes. I am thinking I don't have a coding problem. But I have been wrong before.

Comment: **It's padding**.

Comment: **Absolutely correct, it was the padding.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra 16 bytes are PKCS#7 padding. The padding is added prior to encryption so it is also encrypted.

If you encrypt with PKCS#7 padding the result is exactly the result you get. The default for "AES CBC in Microsoft NET System.Security.Cryptography" is PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding.

Since the data to be encrypted is an exact multiple of the block size an entire block of padding is added.

See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

See [online encryption](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=00000000000000000000000000000000&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101010101010101010101010101010&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2E66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2E0143DB63EE66B0CDFF9F69917680151E), the trailing `10101010101010101010101010101010` is the padding added to the data to be encrypted.

Comment: Because AES is a block cypher and the block size is 16 bytes I should be able to add the padding to my plain text and get the same crypto out.  Sadly it doesn't work. Nor does changing the padding options seem to have any effect on the output. I tried all 5 and got identical crypto text out.

Comment: Adding your own padding will work if you specify no padding on encryption but it seems you are having trouble specifying that option in your code. I have done it with my AES encryption test and the link above also demonstrates it. You need to add your code to the question.

Comment: **That link was the key for me to solve my mystery, thank you again**

Answer (score 3):

If you decrypt without padding you would see this:

```
00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

That is how a **PKCS5/7** padding looks. Here it's padded with 16 bytes, and thus the padding byte is 16 (0x10).

Comment: I tried encrypting just that string and got as crypto-text:66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2E9434DEC2D00FDAC765F00C0C11628CD111E673F8F16AAB7280F66CD9DCD45E01A585E8FFFC87499A864A71883913C95E If you delete the mystery 16 bytes at the end sadly it still doesn't match up.

Comment: The "mystery 16 bytes at the end" is PKCS#7 padding, it is not a mystery.